# Tempus Dominus 6 in Laravel - prevent input to autofill with current time when selecting the date

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

In the input box from Tempus Dominus when selecting the date,  it autofills automatically the current time and I want to leave only the time picker to select the available working hours from which I did disabled the 21-08 non -working hours. I couldn't find this option in the Tempus Dominus documentation.

I did try the option useCurrent: false it did not work.